# Let $k$ a field, $k'$ a subfield, and $A$ any associative $k$-algebra. Can a quotient of $A$ ever yield $k'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebras

I am trying to learn some basic Scheme theory out of Eisenbud's book "Schemes: the Language of Modern Algebraic Geometry." I'm trying to understand how elements of a ring can be treated as functions over spec in the classical sense. Of course, the title is a little broad for this interpretation. However, this question arose as I was trying to solve another question in the book. My intuition tells me the answer is no, but I haven't been able to come up with a satisfying proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: in particular, I mean for $k'$ to be a proper subfield of $k$, and the quotient of $A$ to be isomorphic to $k'$ as a ring.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "yield $k'$"?  A quotient of $A$ could be isomorphic to $k'$ as a ring (indeed, $k$ itself could be isomorphic to $k'$ as a ring).

Comment: @EricWofsey good point, I'll edit my post. I meant specifically that $k'$ is a proper subfield and the quotient of $A$ is isomorphic to $k'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is possible.  For instance, let $L$ be any field and let $k=L(x_0,x_1,\dots)$ be a field of rational functions in infinitely many variables and $k'=L(x_1,x_2,\dots)$.  Then $k'$ is isomorphic to $k$ (just shift the variables), so we can take $A=k$ and the quotient by the zero ideal.

Comment: That's a good answer I hadn't considered. I guess that highlights why the algebras must be finitely generated in classical algebraic geometry. This clearly doesn't hold in the finite case, however. Again, my intuition points to a negative answer for this having a solution in the finite case, but can you give any hints as to why or why not?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the finite case".

Comment: I mean $A$ finitely generated over $k$

Comment: $A$ is finitely generated over $k$ in my example (it's just $k$ itself!).

Comment: Note that in the context of algebraic geometry over a field $k$, we normally only work with $k$-algebras, not arbitrary rings.  There are no proper sub-$k$-algebras of $k$ at all, so there are not even any potential choices of $k'$ in that context.

Comment: ahh that answered the question I was trying to formulate in my head. Thanks for the quick response and the truly brutal counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Let $k \to A$ be the structure map and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$. Then the composition $k \to A \to A/I$ is nonzero and therefore injective.

EDIT: As Eric Wofsey points out this is in fact possible, as long as $k'$ contains a copy of $k$, which shouldn't be possible in many cases we care about (e.g if $k=\mathbb{C}$ and $k'$ is the real numbers)